# How to randomized a group of images in imageview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, random, imageview, sharedpreferences

I'm a beginner on android development and I am creating a game like 4Pics1Word for my project. **I'm wondering on how can I randomized the images by 4. Every activities must have 4 images and those images must be related to each other, thus, 4 pics 1 word.** So I'm thinking I can put **descriptions** on each image and then randomized it then use a control statement in order to g**et those 4 pictures with matching descriptions**. I only need to randomized it in order to randomized the levels (so each application will not have the same consecutive levels). Any ideas? Thank youuuu!

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. A lot of us want to help you but please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public void start() {
    MyImage[] images = /* a list of your images */
    ImageView[] imageViews = /* a list of your imageViews (in this case, 4)*/
    fillImageViews(/* the desc */, imageViews, images);
}




private class MyImage() {
    Drawable image;
    String desc;

    public MyImage(Drawable img, String description) {
        image = img;
        desc = description;

    }

}

public void fillImageViews(String desc, ImageView[] views, MyImage[] images) {
    ArrayList<Integer> usedIndexs = new ArrayList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (ImageView v : views) { 
        while (usedIndexs.size() < images.length) {
            int index = rand.nextInt(images.length);
            if (images[index].desc.equals(desc) && !usedIndexs.contains(index)) {
                //description matches
                v.setImageDrawable(images[index].image);
                usedIndexs.add(index);
                break;
            }
            usedIndexs.add(index);
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is find a random picture in a list and checks to see if it has been used yet and if the description matches. It will keep pulling random pictures until it has tried them all or all the ImageViews get filled. Haven't tried it myself but the code should work.

**Another Idea**: It might be better to have all Images of the same description in it own arraylist. That way you can just pull a random picture from the said arraylist. ex:

```
ArrayList<Drawable> catPics = new ArrayList();
//add cat pics here
ArrayList<Drawable> dogPics = new ArrayList();
//add dogs pics here

//And now you could make function to pull the pictures
public Drawable getRandomPicture(ArrayList<Drawable> imgs) {
    return imgs.get(new Random.nextInt(imgs.size()));
}
```

Comment: Heyy! Thank you very much! I'll try that! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
// In drwable folder your imagename like img_0,img_1,img_2.....img_N



     String imagename = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(N);// N is Maximum random number 
     imageView.setImageDrawable(
        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(imagename, "drawable",
            getApplicationContext()))
        );
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to have a group of 4 related pictures to randomize. So let's just say my game has 5 activities. Each activities are consist of 4 pictures that are related to each other. So I'm gonna be using 20 pictures. And those 20 pictures will be divided by 5. Every group has 4 pictures that are related to each other. So how am I gonna randomized those group of pictures?

Comment: same concept you apply all activity but change images name in activity..example if i want display apple image only in activity A means your imagename  should be like apple_0..apple_5..the random number 5...then imagename = "apple_" + rnd.nextInt(N)